# How can I map a 2 tables (1:many) to a single domain object in fluent NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Lets say I have Person (Id, Name) and Address (Id, PersonId, Address, IsPrimary) tables with 1 to 0..2 relation. This both should be mapped to a single domain object Person like this:

```
public class Person()
{
  public virtual string Name;
  public virtual string PrimaryAddress;
  public virtual string SecondaryAddress;
}
```

IsPrimary column defines if it is a primary (=true) or secondary (=false) address. 
So eventually it should be two left joins with additional condition IsPrimary=1 or IsPrimary=0.

Is it possible to do this type of mapping in fluent NH? How it might look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that in this instance, you're not really doing a one to many mapping. Perhaps it would be better to have your person table more like Person(Id, Name, PrimaryAddressId, OtherAddressId). If you want to do the one to many thing, why not map it one to many then make Primary and Secondary addresses properties that look for the appropriate address in a:

```
public virtual IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

property? I guess that's what makes more sense to me.

Comment: 1) Firstly, I'm not allowed to change DB schema, I can only do change c# code and NH mapping  
2) I would be satisfied with List of Addresses in Person domain object, but the issue I met is an inability to do sorting by any of Address columns that need to be done on SQL level before paging applied. If you can advise me how to do left join with sorting by one of joined field in NH, it would help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Why does sorting matter here? You can use the list of addresses as a holder (that correctly represents your database) then create properties to pull the primary and secondary addresses out. The setter on the property can do the right thing and interact with the list, too. From your question, it sounds like there will be at most 2 addresses per person, correct?

Comment: Correct, it's at most 2 records. However the tricky thing is eventually I have to generate SQL statement like this SELECT ... FROM Person left join Address a1 ON ... LEFT JOIN Address a2 ON ... WHERE a1.IsPrimary=1 and a2.IsPrimary=0 ORDER BY a1.Address. Let me know if it is possible in NH other than through the mapping

Comment: I don't believe it's possible as far as the Person mapping goes. Depending on the use case, this sounds like a query that may be better off in a stored procedure.

Comment: Oh, also ... if you haven't checked it out already, I highly recommend http://www.nhprof.com/ ... it helps A LOT as far as seeing what's going on under the covers with all your NHibernate calls. I usually go through a few iterations of a complicated query and check them out in NHProf to see what they are doing.

Comment: Yes, we are using NH Profiler. Cool tool. If only it allows to convert any SQL statements back to LINQ/NH statements ... :)
Thanks anyway!
I'm still not able vote up your post unfortunatelly having only 13 points. Need to have 15 to vote you up